# Lost .NET standard 2.0 option in VS2017 after .NET 5.0 SDK installation

Tags: visual-studio-2017, .net-5, .net-standard-2.0

I have both VS2017 Pro and VS2019 Pro installed. I use the older one for desktop apps, because the editor is so much faster and more stable, and the newer one for web development only.

After installing the .NET 5 SDK I lost .NET standard 2.0 in VS2017:

[image]

dotnet --info shows

[image]

How do I get .NET Standard 2.0 back?

Comment: I'm not sure how to get it back as I never use that dropdown (too inconsistent for me), but targeting .NET Standard 2.0 is as simple as: `<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53709476/missing-net-standard-2-0-framework-with-latest-net-core-sdk-2-2-1-net-framew

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was add a new system environmental variable MSBuildSdksPath and set it point to an older SDK folder, like C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.110\Sdks. After that netstandard2.0 reappeared in the list.

Answering to myself because this solution was not mentioned in the existing similar thread.